# What is the right way to capture the output of Format-Table (to show it on the host, rather than the stdout)?

Tags: powershell

I’ve got a few functions that return an array of PsCustomObjects, and returning other *stuff* would be bad.

Yet, at times, I’d like to pass in `-Verbose` and spit out some information to the host (using `Write-Host`). I can easily implement `Test-Verbose`, but when I want to spit out a table (with `Format-Table`), it’s not as easy as capturing the output and piping it to `Write-Host`.

What is the right way to show the output of `Format-Table` to the host, without sending it to the stdout, where it will be tallied as part of the function’s return values?

For example:

```
$objects | Format-Table | Write-Host
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `Out-String`. For example, change you example to:

```
$objects | Format-Table | Out-String | Write-Host
```

Does that work?

Comment: OMG, that is perfect. Thanks!!